# Why can't line segment homotopy pass through the origin?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The following example is in the start of section 2.2 in Hatcher's $\textit{Algebraic Topology}$.

If $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ has no fixed points then $\deg f = (-1)^{n+1}$. For if $f(x) \neq x$ then the line segment from $f(x)$ to $-x$ defined by $t \longmapsto (1-t)f(x) - tx$ for $0 \le t \le 1$ does not pass through the origin. Hence if $f$ has no fixed points, $f_t(x) = \frac{(1-t)f(x) - tx}{|(1-t)f(x) - tx|}$ defines a homotopy from $f$ and the antipodal map...

In particular, I don't understand why the line segment $\textit{not}$ passing through the origin means that it is a homotopy. What is the logic? Why do we care if it passes through the origin? I've seen the same idea show up in other proofs, so I think I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it does not go through the origin implies the formula is well-defined (and we are not deviding by 0). The formula varies continuously in $t$, and the endpoints fit, so the homotopy part is clear. But well-definedness is the point.

Comment: I understand not dividing by 0, but how does not passing through the origin ensure the homotopy is well-defined? I'm struggling to see why a homotopy (say defined just by the numerator) wouldn't be well-defined. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The line segment map already defines an homotopy. This should be standard. Dividing by the norm makes it a map into the circle. This only allowed when we never pass 0 so the division is well-defined.